# How would “distraint of knighthood” law in medieval England fit with the fact that all knights must be of noble birth?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, england, early-modern, nobility

I've read recently about “[distraint of knighthood](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095722567)” law in medieval England started by Henry III but I found it very strange indeed. 
This law forced all rich people who has 40 £ or more to be knighted by the king or pay fine instead. 
However, many of those rich people were not necessarily nobles, but rather, rich merchants, patricians craftsmen, yeomen, and non-noble landowners. 
Such law will create a large group of knights (thus becoming nobles) who are of non-noble birth! even if they are rich they are still seen by nobles and clergy as commoners. This is quite against the common fact that all medieval nobles were of noble birth, so how would this law fit with these contradictions?

Also, was this law only in medieval England? Were there any similar laws in other parts of Europe?

Comment: Please cite all terms.. The question cannot be tagged both early modern and early medieval).  The King made the law - the king was not bound by the law ; that is the nature of autocracy.  If the king needed funds, the king created law that provided grounds to raise the funds.  Although we today use the term "middle class" to understand economic changes, the term was not available to legal scholars in this period.  If you had the money to support the king, the king could oblige you to grant that money

Comment: Knights were not necessarily nobles (nor were nobles necessarily knights).

Comment: Thanks for advice @MarkC.Wallace
Actually I understand why the king issued the law, but I don't understand its social effect on those non-noble rich men. 
sempaiscuba mentioned that not all knights were nobles, so would that mean that they would be knights ready to fight armored for the king while he wouldn't give them any land or title in return because of their non-noble birth?

Comment: @MarkCWallace I've gone and changed your link to point to something more in line with the question. Note that Charles I (as per the [Personal Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Rule) article) revived the old medieval concept started by Henry III so that he (Charles) could raise money. It was a legalism.

Comment: @AnasAlbakri Worth reading something like [Knighthood and Chivalry](https://www.heraldica.org/topics/orders/knights.htm) for an overview.  Note that in the feudal system, most knights actually owed allegiance to members of the nobility, rather than directly to the king.

Comment: Knights (in general) were commoners - only Barons and higher, the *peers of the realm*, were noble. Certainly barons could also be knights, and usually were, but at least 90% if not 95% of all knights were common.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: In England post 1066 ***all land*** was held *in fee* from the king - it being his by right of conquest - even if often indirectly though a *tenant-in-chief* and possibly one level of *sub-tenant*. This is the basis upon which *expropriation* can and is still performed by the *crown* in all British Commonwealth Westminster countries.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens True.  But the knight owed his service to his lord (the _tenant-in-chief_ or _sub-tenant_) rather than directly to the king.  That is how rivals were able to raise armies to fight the various civil wars (The Anarchy, Wars of the Roses, etc).

Comment: You appear to continue missing the point that *knights* were the original basis of what became later the [landed gentry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landed_gentry) - the **non-noble** aristocracy and professionals of independent wealth based upon land ownership. The *baronets*, *knights*, *esquires*, and *gentlemen* of Victorian Englnad were the basis of the *gentry*.

Comment: Knights were not necessarily of noble birth.  For instance, soldiers could be knighted for valor in battle.  This continues to the present day, as for example the three US soldiers who were knighted by France in 2015 for stopping a jihadist attack.

Answer (score 1):

Knights were not peers.  Indeed, even though baronetcies were inheritable, baronets were not peers either.  When a knight was sent to Parliament, it was to sit in the House of Commons, not the House of Lords.

Also, it was the prerogative of a king to ennoble people.  There was a status accorded to having been of long noble descent, but a man ennobled by the king was certainly a noble.

Answer (score 0):

The original definition of ["noble"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobility) was someone who owned a large amount of land. At minimum, it referred to someone who could afford to buy and deploy a horse for use in combat. These were the people whom the king granted "fiefdoms" to under the feudal system that made them nobles.

There was an important feature of nobility that held true in England, and later France, but not in most parts of central and Eastern Europe. That is, [only the eldest son](http://www.avictorian.com/aristocracy_primogeniture.html) could inherit a noble title from his father. (In France, all sons could.) This English rule, together with the general fact that sons inherited a noble rank one lower than their fathers (the son of a duke was a marquis, the son of a count was a viscount, etc.), meant that English nobles would die out after several generations unless the pool was replenished.

So the king's decree meant that anyone who had x pounds or more, and could afford a horse (and armor and a weapon), to buy such, and in return receive a grant of knighthood, and thus nobility. This restored "nobility" to its original purpose, and served the interests of the king, who wanted to create as many mounted warriors (and hence nobles) as could support themselves. Of course, this displeased most existing nobles, whose nobility had been procured by an ancestor, and who wanted to prevent others from doing the same in the present.

It would be as if members of the top 1% were asked to demonstrate their membership by buying and making available a tank for the use of the government.

Comment: It is simply false that a son inherits one rank lower than his father.  A duke's son is a duke, when he inherits.  Before he inherits, he may be called a marquis because that is the highest subsidiary title of the duke, and it used as a courtesy for the heir apparent, but that's only until he inherits.